# Why are graph-structured molecules invariant to the ordering of atoms?

Tags: computational-chemistry, machine-learning

In order to train GANs (Generative Adversarial Networks) on QM9 dataset, the dataset is converted to graph format as graph-structured molecules are invariant to the ordering of atoms. I want to understand why graph-structured molecules are invariant to the ordering of atoms.

Comment: Can you point to the paper that is using this format to learn from the QM9 dataset?

Comment: Whether the graph is invariant to atom order depends a **lot** on how the graph is represented.

Comment: @Tyberius, https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.03438 is the paper and the github link is https://github.com/jundeli/quantum-gan --------------------------------------------- Quoting from github page--------------------------------------------- 
data: should contain your datasets. If you run download_dataset.sh the script will download the dataset used for the paper (then you should run data/sparse_molecular_dataset.py to conver the dataset in a graph format used by MolGAN models)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, thanks ..... what kind of representation of graphs is invariant to atom order...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is a requirement for GANs (algorithms are designed that way), ie, it is your job to translate the problems to a representation where the graphs have this invariance.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out?